# Is it wrong to create function with two different parameter initials defined by template parameter

Tags: c++

According to my understanding of template,

```
template<class it>
foo(it num1, it num2)  //both it forms int 
{
    num1=30;
    num2=20;

    cout<<num1<<endl;
    cout<<num2<<endl;

}

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    foo(num1,num2)
    return 0;
}
```

What if I wanted the function parameter to have string on one side, and int on the other side of function parameter like

```
template<class it>
foo(it num1, it alp)  //both it on left int, it on right string , if i had declared
                      // it on right as "string" instead of "it", it works just fine. 
{
    num1=30;
    alp="Name";

    cout<<num1<<endl;
    cout<<num2<<endl;  

}

int main()
{
    int num1; string alp; 
    foo(num1,alp)
    return 0;
}
```

Template is generic, and lets you put any data type right? If so, shouldn't my program be legal?

Comment: Have you tried something like `template<class iit, class sit>`?

Comment: I've noticed that you've already asked a bunch of questions, but didn't accept any answer (yet). If you're not satisfied with an answer, leave a comment, otherwise [accept one of the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Zeta- i am so sorry. I was unaware of what I was supposed to do after getting the answer that solved my problem. Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If so, shouldn't my program be legal?

No. In a simple sense, you can think of the template parameter `it` as placeholder for a type. But then `it` is the type for *both* parameters, so you would end up with either `foo(int,int)` or `foo(string, string)`. Instead, use a second template parameter:

```
template<class T, class U>
foo(T num1, U alp)
{
    num1=30;
    alp="Name";

    cout<<num1<<endl;
    cout<<alp<<endl;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally when using template compiler replaces all uses of `it` in your case with class that you provide. So your code can be legal only if the class you provide to it will have defined `operator=(&it, const char*)` and `operator=(&it, int)`, but it wont work for just `int` "class" or `string`.